# Delete from a table with right join including a limit

Tags: mysql, sql

When I tried to delete from a table with right join is working, when I added a `LIMIT` query fails :

```
DELETE la 
FROM log_artim la
RIGHT JOIN corm_artim ca ON la.idCorm = ca.id 
WHERE la.da <= '2022-02-02 02:02:02'
LIMIT 10
```

If I remove limit is working fine, if not I have an error :

`MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 10' at line 5`

Have an idea about hits error ?

Comment: What is it that you actually want to achieve? What rows do you want to delete? Please provide example data and expected output.

Comment: It's always worth a trip to the manual - 'The LIMIT clause places a limit on the number of rows that can be deleted. These clauses apply to single-table deletes, but not multi-table deletes.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html

Comment: Need more help? - publish table definitions, sample data and expected outcome as text.

Answer (score 0):

As per MYSQL [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html#idm45354680744576)

> You cannot use 'ORDER BY' or 'LIMIT' in a multiple-table DELETE.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use LIMIT clause, you should see below code;

```
DELETE la 
FROM log_artim la
WHERE la.id in (
  SELECT la.id 
  FROM log_artim la
  RIGHT JOIN corm_artim ca ON la.idCorm = ca.id 
  WHERE la.da <= '2022-02-02 02:02:02'
  LIMIT 10
)
```

Comment: This is not how I would expect the original query to behave. Your query deletes all rows referring to the first 10 rows from `log_artim`. I would expect the original query to delete at most 10 rows.

Answer (score 0):

The following query shall work for you using `LIMIT` clause

```
delete from log_artim 
where idCorm in (
  select la.idCorm
  from log_artim la
  right join corm_artim ca on la.idCorm = ca.id 
  where la.da <= '2022-02-02 02:02:02'
  limit 10
);
```

Update :

> To resolve the issue :
> This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

You can modify the above query as :

```
delete log_artim
from log_artim
right join (
  select la.idCorm
  from log_artim la
  inner join corm_artim ca on la.idCorm = ca.id 
  where la.da <= '2022-02-02 02:02:02'
  limit 10
) t1 on log_artim.idCorm = t1.idCorm;
```

Comment: the error message : This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: Hi @klsdskldsd; I have modified my query to fit older versions of mysql.
Can you please check whether it works for you ?